# How to update data in join table in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I am building an app with Rails 4 using Devise and CanCan. When a new user registers they are not given a default role. The admin has to manually assign it through the admin panel. And that's where I am running into difficulty. I can't figure out how to update the data in the join field. Here's what I have so far.

My UsersController:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]


   def index
    authorize! :index, @user, message: 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    authorize! :update, @user, message: 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, alert: "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize! :destroy, @user, message: 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    unless @user == current_user
      @user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "User deleted."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "Can't delete yourself."
    end
  end

  private
     def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role_id, :user_id)
  end
  end
```

And my role model:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  scopify
end
```

And my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

As you can see it's pretty much the standard model as generated by Devise.

And here's the form I'm using to update the role:

```
<div id="role-options-<%= user.id %>" class="reveal-modal medium" style="display: none;">
  <%= simple_form_for user, url: user_path(user), html: {method: :put, class: 'custom' } do |f| %>
      <h3>Change Role</h3>
      <%= f.input :role_ids, collection: Role.all, as: :radio_buttons, label_method: lambda {|t| t.name.titleize}, label: false, item_wrapper_class: 'inline', checked: user.role_ids.first %>
      <%= f.submit "Change Role", class: "small button" %>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal" href="#">Close</a>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When I check the new role on the form and submit it, I am redirected to the users page with the message "User updated."  However, the user role has not been updated.

I'm still fairly new to Rails and just can't figure out exactly what I am doing wrong. If I understand correctly, I need to update the data in the user_roles table. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Probably, you should change `UsersController#user_params` to permit `:role_ids`

Comment: How many roles one user can have?

Comment: @taro Bang on! That's what the problem was. If you submit it as an answer, I would happily choose it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using string params, but forgot to add role_ids into allowed fields.

So, your controller should contain something like this (in case role_ids is an array):

```
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role_ids => [])
  end
```

Or if role_ids is scalar, just drop `=> []` part.

[More info could be found here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what rolify does. But I would do this:

```
class User
  has_one :users_roles
  has_one :role, through: :users_roles
```

I am not sure about this though. But you could give it a try. I know `has_one :users_roles` is weird.